# How can I sorting ListView by trailing value in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, sorting, flutter-listview, trailing

I have a ListView in Flutter shows stores location information from firebase after that a function works to calculate a distance between customer location and stores locations and show distance value in the trailing of ListView, now I want to sort this ListView based on trailing value (nearest stores):

[image: SCREENSHOT FROM LIST VIEW]

Most of solution I have tried was so complicated and want an easy a effective way.

Comment: Hi, can you share the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For ascending*

```
var dataList = [1, 6, 8, 2, 16, 0] //your dynamic list
dataList.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
```

*For descending*

```
var dataList  = [1, 6, 8, 2, 16, 0] //your dynamic list
dataList .sort((b, a) => a.compareTo(b));
```

don't forgot to call setState to reload your UI again

Comment: Thank you Harizh, I believe this is the easiest way, it 'is collecting the result in a separate list then sort it then return it back to widget.